# How can I assign a struc to a void pointer passed through the paramters?

Tags: c, void-pointers

In my code I have a struc

```
struct Test {
    int a;  
    int b;
    char c;
};
```

With my function:

```
int TestFunction(void* ptr){
    struct Test test;
    test.a = 0;
    test.b = 1;
    strcpy(c,"hello");

    return 0;
    }
```

Now to link the temp struc to the void ptr I passed in I have

```
struct Test* temp = (struct Test*)ptr;
struct Test test = *temp;
```

Is this the correct way to link strucs with void ptrs? Is there an easier way?

Comment: "*Is this the correct way to link strucs with void ptrs?*" -- It is *a* way. Whether it is the correct way depends on the results you are expecting. Are you expecting modifications to the struct to be visible in the struct pointed to?

Comment: Do you want to modify the original struct that was passed in or only a copy of it? And what is `strcpy(c,"hello");` meant to do as `c` is undeclared? Also, `void` pointers can be assigned to any other pointer type. So the cast is not needed and thus the simpler: `struct Test* temp = ptr;`

Comment: @Dolda2000, yep I want to modify the void ptr struc when the function returns

Comment: @kaylum the char is a typo, but thanks for the info about the simplification

Comment: We meant do you want the struct modifications *inside* the function to be on the original struct or a copy? That is, do you want `test.a = 0;` to make the original struct's `a` field be set to 0?

Comment: @kaylum yes whatever is done in the function would modify the original struc

Comment: ok, then your code as shown does not achieve that as it operates on a *copy* of the original struct. The answer from @Dolda2000 is what you are looking for.

Comment: By the way, you seem to be using the word "struc" consistently. The correct term is "struct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to be able to modify the struct pointed to, your sample code is not appropriate. What it does is create a local copy of the pointed-to struct and modifies the local copy instead of the original object.

What you want to do, rather, is this:

```
int TestFunction(void *ptr) {
    struct Test *test = ptr;
    test->a = 0;
    test->b = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

The `a->b` syntax is equivalent to `(*a).b`, meaning that it refers to whatever `test` points to.

Comment: thanks! Would you be able to show an example with arrays and strings too? would it look like test->arr = myarr, assuming myarr is an array declared and test->str = mystring?

Comment: @chonglawr: It works exactly the same as for a local variable of the type you want to modify. As for arrays, you can never assign to arrays, be they local variables or struct members.

Comment: Just to clarify, why wouldn't my original code work, when I create temp and point it to ptr, in test I am getting the value of temp, isn't that the same as what you have in you set test equal to temp and you deref for the struct?

Comment: @chonglawr: Because your `test` is a local variable. Doing `struct Test test = *temp;` creates a local variable `test` and *copies* the contents of the struct that `temp` points to into it. Essentially, at this point you have two `struct Test` objects: one that `ptr` and `temp` point to, and one that `test` has allocated in the current stack frame. Your modifications go to the latter, and the former is left unchanged.